# Get comment authors on Youtube

Tags: loops, youtube, comments

I want to loop though all the comments' authors text in videos on Youtube and save it somewhere one after another, but I'm having a hard time with it. I tried using Greasemonkey and writing something in jquery but it doesn't seem to run on youtube, I don't know if they blocked jquery? I had a little success in using javascript but still having undefined errors on variables, as well as some functions that aren't working with it. So can anyone suggest a way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop though all the comments' authors text in videos on Youtube and save it somewhere one after another, then for this you can use jquery, if you have broad knowledge in jquery you can use here or you can take helps w3schools.com for solving your problems. [Youtube comments](http://www.buyyoutubelikes.com/youtube-comments/) plays an important role to show your popularity. To know more visit:- http://www.buyyoutubelikes.com/youtube-comments/